# asp.net core docker issue on dotnet restore

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, nuget-package, dotnet-restore

I am new to docker and I developed a simple asp.net core webapi solution which uses a NuGet package from a private repository.

*dotnet restore* command returns an error for a missing NuGet package that is located inside a private repository which introduced in the nuget.config file inside the solution.

does anyone knows what's the problem with my configs and dockerfile ?

Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "aspnetcoretssl.dll"]
```

.dockerignore

```
bin\
obj\
```

Also I have a nuget.config file in the solution's root directory as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="myrepo" value="\\path\to\the\nuget_packages_folder" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

But I receive below messages from

***docker build -t aspnetcoretssl .***

> error NU1101: Unable to find package TestContracts. No packages exist
>   with this id in source(s): nuget.org   Generating MSBuild file
>   /app/obj/aspnetcoretssl.csproj.nuget.g.props.
>
> The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet restore' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: most likely you run dotnet restore inside linux container and it cannot access your custom nuget dirrectory located on some windows shared folder

Comment: @PavelAgarkov , yes this was my initial guess, but by providing nuget.config inside solution it suppose to be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are two problems

1. The NuGet.config file is in your solution directory, but the Dockerfile is in the project folder. This means `COPY . ./` won't copy NuGet.config into the Docker container
2. Even if you had the NuGet.config file, the "myrepo" source is an invalid filepath inside a Docker container.

This is invalid because this is a Windows network file path, but your container is running on Linux.

To solve this, I would recommend the following.

1. Either move your Dockerfile to the solution directory, or move NuGet.config into the project directory.
2. Add a second file named NuGet.linux.config, and point to this file when building on non-windows. Use the RestoreConfigFile property to point to this file when building on Linux. If you have moved NuGet.config into the project directory, adding these lines to your `aspnetcoretssl.csproj` files would work:

   ```
   <PropertyGroup>
     <RestoreConfigFile Condition="'$(OS)' != 'Windows_NT'">NuGet.linux.config</RestoreConfigFile>
     <RestoreConfigFile Condition="'$(OS)' == 'Windows_NT'">NuGet.config</RestoreConfigFile>
   </PropertyGroup>
   ```
3. Creating a network mount from `\\path\to\the\nuget_packages_folder` to `Z:\`
4. In `NuGet.linux.config`, change "myrepo" to  `<add key="myrepo" value="/nuget/myrepo" />`
5. Mounting this drive into the container. This is done with the `--volume` parameter on docker-run. `docker run --volume Z:/:/nuget/myrepo`